# EBS volumes on EMR cluster with CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to launch an EMR cluster using AWS CloudFormation. I'd like to add EBS volumes to my core instances, however neither the [`AWS::EMR::Cluster`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-cluster.html) nor the [`AWS::EMR::InstanceGroupConfig`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-instancegroupconfig.html) resource types mention anything about EBS volumes. I see you can attach EBS volumes [via the API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_InstanceGroup.html), but CloudFormation will not accept these settings.

Is this possible to do via CloudFormation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to launch Amazon EMR clusters with attached EBS volumes was [introduced in February 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-emr-update-support-for-ebs-volumes-and-m4-c4-instance-types/) (a month prior to this question being posted).

It is likely that CloudFormation has not yet been updated to enable this additional configuration. It is quite common for CloudFormation to lag behind new feature releases.

When available, the configuration will likely be added to the [Amazon Elastic MapReduce Cluster JobFlowInstancesConfig InstanceGroupConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-emr-cluster-jobflowinstancesconfig-instancegroupconfig.html).

Comment: Didn't realise it was such a new feature, makes sense I don't see it in CloudFormation then.